# run stored procedure in python using pymssql

Tags: python, stored-procedures

while executing stored procedure using pymssql getting error:

> _mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (8144, b'Procedure or function GET_USER_DETAILS has too many arguments specified. DB-Lib error
>   message 8144, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages
>   from the SQL Server\n')

code snippet:

```
        connection = self.engine.raw_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        args= ('user')
        cursor.callproc("GET_USER_DETAILS", args)
        cursor.nextset()
        result = list(cursor.fetchone())
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()
        print(result)
```

stored procedure GET_USER_DETAILS, accept only one parameter, thats user name.

Comment: `cursor.callproc("GET_USER_DETAILS", (args,))`

Comment: wow, that worked..@BurhanKhalid

Answer (score 1):

The below code is working.

```
        connection = self.engine.raw_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        args= ('user')
        cursor.callproc("GET_USER_DETAILS", (args,))
        cursor.nextset()
        result = list(cursor.fetchone())
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()
        print(result)
```